# Append elements based on its parent and children from recursive function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion

I'm getting all comments for a post in subreddit and I need to display them in Reddit style.

It means every comment has its parent and children. I try to display them with the following structure.

`<div class="comment" id="comment.id" >
   <div class="body> comment.body </div>
   <div class="replies> Add one level lower comments </div>
 </div>`

To structure everything I use this recursive function, but I struggle with appending comments on the page.

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/DHKtW/572/

And this is an example for what design I'm trying to achieve, but not in the proper way - http://jsfiddle.net/DHKtW/573/ Instead of this, it should just insert all child comments under `<div class="replies> </div>`

```js
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/science/comments/40h4go.json?", function(data) { 
    console.log(data[1].data.children);
    checkComments(data[1].data.children,0);
});


function checkComments(comments, deep) {

    var replies = '<div class="replies"> </div>';
    
    for (comment in comments) {
        console.log(comments[comment].data,deep);
      
        element = comments[comment].data;
        
        var body = '<div class="body"><p>' + element.body + '</p></div>'

        var $comment = $('<div id="comment-'+element.name+'" class="comment"> 'body + replies +' </div>');
        
        child_comments = comments[comment].data.replies;
        if (child_comments) {
            checkComments(child_comments.data.children,deep+1);
        }
    }
}
```

```
.replies {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken of what you're trying to achieve.

I had to rename some of your variables because it misled me.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/science/comments/40h4go.json?", function(data) { 
    addComments($('.comments'), data[1].data.children);
});

function addComments(parentElem, comments)
{
    for (comment in comments)
    {
        var commentData = comments[comment].data;
        var bodyElem = '<div class="body"><p>' + commentData.body + '</p></div>';
        var $commentElem = $('<div id="comment-' + commentData.parent_id + '" class="comment" style="margin-left: 10px">' + bodyElem + '</div>');
        parentElem.append($commentElem);

        if (commentData.replies)
        {
            var $replyElem = $('<div class="replies"> </div>');
            $commentElem.append($replyElem);
            addComments($replyElem, commentData.replies.data.children);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DHKtW/577/)

Comment: Wish I could tip money in here. They should seriously add such a feature. Thank you, kind sir.

Comment: @mhlavacka Please check the updated answer. It'd remove all wasteful `.replies` that doesn't have any content.